# Java 7 SE вызов метода класса по имени

Tags: java

Есть несколько классов вида:

```
package ru.com.project.service;

public class Hashing {

    public static String Hash ( String data ) {
        return data;
    }

}
```

Пытаюсь вызвать метод нужного класса по имени:

```
String serviceName = "Hashing";
String serviceMethod = "Hash";

Class service = Class.forName( "ru.com.project.service." + serviceName );
Method classMethod = service.getMethod( serviceMethod );
```

Класс находится, и возврате

```
service.getMethods()
```

есть искомый метод, но на строке

```
Method classMethod = service.getMethod( serviceMethod );
```

валится ошибка

> (java.lang.NoSuchMethodException) java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: ru.com.project.service.Hashing.Hash()

Что ему не нравится, я не понимаю...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Используйте другой метод](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class...)). Передайте типы параметров этого метода и будет работать. Сейчас вы пытаетесь найти метод без параметров.

Comment: Тогда странно, что он бросает исключение, а не возвращает *null*. Спасибо.

Comment: В документации написано что кидается ошибка, поведение предсказуемо